# Running C code on Mac OS mavericks gives infinite loop but works fine with Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c, macos, gcc

The below code works fine on ubuntu gcc but goes into infinite loop on mac OS mavericks. using gcc48 on both.
It is for OS assignment hence I have to use contexts and cannot use POSIX.
When I run it on MAC it runs "Print" infinite time

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 6000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

void callback()
{
  printf("callback start\n");
}

int main(void) {
  ucontext_t ctx;
  getcontext(&ctx);
  ctx.uc_stack.ss_sp   = malloc( sizeof(char) * 8192 );
  ctx.uc_stack.ss_size = 8192;
  ctx.uc_link = NULL;
  printf("Print\n");
  makecontext(&ctx, callback, 0);
  setcontext(&ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to wikipedia: "Citing portability concerns, POSIX.1-2004 obsoleted these functions, and in POSIX.1-2008 they were removed, and POSIX Threads recommended."

Comment: Note that `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 6000` is trying to invoke a future edition of the X/Open standard; the current number is 700 (seven hundred, compared with six thousand).  It is not clear that things would work better with a more plausible value such as 600, but you should avoid leaving your code open to such misunderstandings.

Comment: Having added `-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations` to override the `-Werror` I normally use, I confirm that Mac OS X (10.9.4) does show an infinite loop (and it is not interruptible, but it can be quit).  The compilation warns that the functions are deprecated.

Comment: I cannot use POSIX as it is an assignment. I am also not using it for ios/iphone development. I have to implement my threading library

Comment: @D.Shawley has already answered the question -- you have to handle the fact that the `getcontext` is going to return twice.  The second time that it returns is after the callback function finishes. So you have to detect that `getcontext` has returned a second time, and return from `main` when that happens.

Answer (score 2):

From my reading of [setcontext(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcontext.html), it should be an infinite loop.  Calling `getcontext` initializes the context.  The following call to `makecontext` configures `ctx` so that it calls `callback` when it is activate.  The final call to `setcontext` follows

> A successful call to setcontext() shall not return; program execution resumes at the point specified by the ucp argument passed to setcontext().

This means that it will call `callback`.  When `callback` returns

> program execution continues as if the corresponding call of getcontext() had just returned

Which results in a new stack allocation followed by a call to `makecontext` and `setcontext`.

The [Apple manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/setcontext.3.html) is even clearer and addresses this exact case.

> The setcontext() function makes a previously saved thread context the
>   current thread context, i.e., the current context is lost and
>   setcontext() does not return.  Instead, execution continues in the con-text context
>   text specified by ucp, which must have been previously initialized by a
>   call to getcontext(), makecontext(3), or by being passed as an argument
>   to a signal handler (see sigaction(2)).
>
> If ucp was initialized by getcontext(), then execution continues as if
>   the original getcontext() call had just returned (again).

I would definitely agree with the comments by @user3386109 and @JonathanLeffler - use POSIX Threads.

Comment: Hmm, no. Apple: _If ucp was initialized by makecontext(3), execution continues with the invocation of the function specified to makecontext(3).  When that function returns, ucp->uc_link determines what happens next: if ucp->uc_link is NULL, the process exits; otherwise, setcontext(ucp->uc_link) is implicitly invoked._

Comment: Linux: _If the context was obtained by a call of makecontext(3), program execution continues by a call to the function func specified as the second argument of that call to makecontext(3).  When the function func returns, we continue with the uc_link member of the structure ucp specified as the first argument of that call to makecontext(3).  When this member is NULL, the thread exits._

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple, just replace 8192 with 32*1024 or MINSIGSTKSZ (from signal.h), then you get the same output on both platforms. The behavior of ucontext on mac is quite different from Linux if one's not careful. I wrote one [post](http://scriptogr.am/albertnetymk/post/adventure-with-ucontext-on-linux-and-mac), if someone is interested.